# Getting Selenium Going for Use with Protractor for my AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I'm building an AngularJS app on Windows. I want to create end-to-end tests with Jasmine. From my understanding, I need protractor to run these kinds of tests. For that reason, I've added the following to my package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
  ...
  "grunt-protractor-runner": "0.2.4",
  "selenium-webdriver":"2.41.0",
  ...
}
```

In my gruntfile.js, I've configured Protractor as such:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  protractor: {
    options: {
      configFile: "node_modules/protractor/referenceConf.js", // Default config file
      keepAlive: true, // If false, the grunt process stops when the test fails.
      noColor: false, // If true, protractor will not use colors in its output.
      args: {
        // Arguments passed to the command
      }
    },
    tests: {
      options: {
        configFile: "tests/config/e2e.conf.js",
        args: {} // Target-specific arguments
      }
    },
  }
});
```

I'm then running the `protractor:tests` target. The contents of e2e.conf.js look like the following:

```
exports.config = {
    // The address of a running selenium server.
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

    // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
    },

    // Spec patterns are relative to the location of the spec file. They may
    // include glob patterns.
    specs: ['../../tests/e2e/user-tests.e2e.js'],

    // Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true, // Use colors in the command line report.
    }
};
```

Now, when I run grunt from the command-line, I get an error that says:

```
Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub

C:\Projects\MyProject\node_modules\grunt-protractor-runner\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1702
      throw error;
            ^
Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED
...
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error. I see in the [Protractor Getting Started Guide](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md) that it expects a selenium standalone server to be running. However, I thought that was the purpose of the Grunt task runner: start the selenium server. I see webdriver-manager in node_modules\grunt-protractor-runner\node_modules\protractor\bin, however, if I change to that directory and run `webdriver-manager update` from the command-line, I get an error that says:

```
'webdriver-manager' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How do I get the selenium piece going so that I can run end-to-end tests with protractor?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with "node" command ?

It worked for me :

```
node .\node_modules\grunt-protractor-runner\node_modules\protractor\bin\webdriver-manager update
```

This should download for you chromedriver and selenium server. If not, ou can also  manually download/extract :

- http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.40/selenium-server-standalone-2.40.0.jar
- https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.9/chromedriver_win32.zip

in :

- src/test/config/selenium/selenium-server-standalone.jar
- src/test/config/selenium/chromedriver.exe

An other thing is that you need to be sure that Chrome is isntalled in :

```
<WINDOWS_USERS_FOLDER>\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

First up:

- There are many components in there that I don't understand :)
- Feel free to add comments to help me improve my answer.
- I do know *some* Selenium so here goes.

> ```
> seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
> ```

To me, this line indicates that you are trying to run the [Selenium Grid Server.](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2)

Here's how to start it: (yes, it needs to be started manually as far as I know)
From a separate console, run the following:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar -role hub
#now wait a few seconds for the hub to start
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar -role node  -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register
```

What did we just do?

- Started a hub. This hub is like a test distributor - it receives the requests.
- Started a node. (You can start any number of nodes). This node is what will actually conduct the test.

You can verify that this server was started successfully. Just visit the local host link on your browser.

Gotchas:

- Check that your firewall is not giving you problems. I've had crippling issues getting started on Windows 7 and finally moved over to Ubuntu (but that's probably just my situation).
- Open ports 4444 (for hub), 5555(for node) for both incoming and outgoing connections on Windows Firewall.